# Relating column names with data from a different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have three DataFrames:

1. One containing the amount of sales per item (row) per day (column).
2. One containing a column with all days and a column with the weeks.
3. One containing a column with all items, their weekly price and a column with the weeks.

What I would like to do is to modify the first table so that instead of displaying the sales it displays that number multiplied by the price that the item had that day. That is (pseudocode):

```
for all items (rows) and days (columns) in table1:

   table1(item, day) = table1(item, day) * table3.prices(item, table2.weeks(day))
```

And I would like to avoid loops and use Pandas operations.

EDIT:

Table 1 is something like this:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|  item | day1 | day2 | day3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item1 |   0  |   2  |   3  |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item2 |   1  |   5  |   3  |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item3 |  12  |   7  |   8  |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Table 2:

```
+------+-------+
|  day |  week |
+------+-------+
| day1 | week1 |
+------+-------+
| day2 | week2 |
+------+-------+
| day3 | week2 |
+------+-------+
```

Table 3:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  item |  week | price |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item1 | week1 |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item1 | week1 |   4   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item2 | week2 |   7   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item2 | week2 |   9   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item3 | week1 |   2   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| item3 | week2 |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Therefore, the expected output would be (if I calculated properly):

```
+-------+------+------+------+
|  item | day1 | day2 | day3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item1 |   0  |   8  | 12   |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item2 |   7  |  45  | 27   |
+-------+------+------+------+
| item3 |  24  |  21  | 24   |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Can you add a simple sample of your data? Also include the expected output from that data.

Comment: @QuangHoang Added a small example.

Comment: There's a duplicate on table3, is the week on second row `week1` or `week2`?

Comment: Oh sorry it was supposed to be week2, I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a double merge:

```
# stack the fist table so we can use `day` information
s=tbl1.melt('item', value_name='unit', var_name='day')

(s.merge(tbl3.merge(tbl2,on='week',how='inner'),
       on=['item','day'], how='outer')
  .assign(total=lambda x: x['unit']*x['price'])
   .pivot(index='item',columns='day',values='total')
)
```

Output:

```
day    day1  day2  day3
item                   
item1     0     8    12
item2     7    45    27
item3    24    21    24
```

---

**Update**:

Another way is to get get the daily price by day and multiply:

```
daily = (tbl3.merge(tbl2,on='week',how='inner')
     .set_index(['item','day']).price
     .unstack()
)

output = tbl1.set_index('item') * daily
```

Output:

```
       day1  day2  day3
item                   
item1     0     8    12
item2     7    45    27
item3    24    21    24
```

Comment: UPDATE: It works, however the melt operation is sorting the days alphabetically: day1, day10, day100, day1000, day1001... And I need it to be sorted chronologically (original order from tbl1), but I'll do some research on how to achieve this.

Comment: You can chain that with `reindex(tbl1.columns, axis=1)`

Comment: I see, thanks. And sorry, it is not the melt operation that changes the order but I cannot edit the comment anymore.

Comment: Just a last extra note in case it helps someone in the future: after reindexing I had to use .reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) so that the items become a column again instead of an index.